# resolving all files from set public directories with webpack

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, bundler

I have built a custom HTML framework that has a pretty simple project structure. I really need to grab from 3 separate directories `views`,`js`, and `components`. I am very new to webpack but I figured with its configurability there would be a way for me to have all of these imports importing  something like `/components/random_component_name.js` I need webpack to resolve these files to be their private path.

I have tried many different things this is what I have most recently tested

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname + '/public/js/main.js'),
  module: {
    generator: {
      js: {
        // Generator options for asset modules
  
        // Customize publicPath for asset modules, available since webpack 5.28.0
        publicPath: '/js',
  
        // Emit the asset in the specified folder relative to 'output.path', available since webpack 5.67.0
        outputPath: path.resolve(__dirname + 'public/js'),
      },
    },
  },
}
```

How can i get this functionality out of webpack. Surely it shouldn't be too hard. I am new to all bundlers like this so sorry if this is horribly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. I had tried a method close to this before but neglected the '/' in the alias key names so now this work

```js
const path = require('path');


module.exports = {
  //...
  entry: {
    main: './src/js/main.js',

  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '/components': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/'),
      '/js': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/'),
      '/views': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/views/'),
    },
  }
};
```